# Can't get my java post request to log in -- maybe an html issue

Tags: java, html, httprequest

I've been trying to get this code to work so that it can send a post to a website to log me in. I'm not sure if there's a problem with my java code or with the way I'm understanding how to read the html code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class LogIn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/login.phtml";

try {

  String destination = "%2Findex.phtml";
  String username = "myUser";
  String password = "myPass";
  String submit = "Log In!";

  String destination_param = "destination";
  String username_param = "username";
  String password_param = "password";
  String submit_param = "submit";

  String encoded_destination = destination_param + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(destination, "UTF-8");
  String encoded_username = username_param + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8"); 
  String encoded_password = password_param + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
  String encoded_submit = submit_param + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(submit, "UTF-8");

  String encoded = encoded_destination + "&" + encoded_username + "&" + encoded_password + "&" + encoded_submit;

    URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    DataOutputStream osw = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    osw.writeBytes(encoded);
    osw.flush();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String in = "";

    while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(in);   
    }

    osw.close();
    br.close();

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The following html code is the login form. Just beside the form method it says "action="/login.phtm"" you'll see in my code that I've added this to my URL. was that correct or should it be just "http://www.example.com"? I've tried both obviously neither seems to work so something else must be wrong and I'm assuming it's the input. You'll see that for each input in the form I've created a encodedURL to submit with my post but it doesn't seem to work. The source code that gets printed out is that of the main webpage and not of my account. Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

```
<form method="post" action="/login.phtml">
        <input type="hidden" id="templateLoginDest" name="destination"    value="%2Findex.phtml">
        <table style="width: 350px;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100px"><b>Username:</b></td>
                <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="username" id="templateLoginPopupUsername" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><b>Password:</b></td>
                <td valign="top"><input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br><a href="/account/passwordreset.phtml" style="font-size: 8pt;">Forgot Password?</a><br><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Log In!"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work"?

Comment: When I'm printing out the inputStream, it prints the page source of the the website homepage. If it were working properly it should print out the page source of my profile because I should be logged in. The program compiles and runs, it's just a matter of sending the right information so that it can log me in.

Comment: Do you understand how "logging in" works?

Comment: I think I understand the basics, I send a post with the required headers and then whatever they do verify my information and then send me what I requested